# Produce PDF/ PNG of a specific aspect ratio

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx, polyglossia, lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount},
  colframe=black,
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=8mm,
  colbacktitle=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\centering,
  overlay app={%
    \node[white, anchor=south, text width=.95\textwidth] at (frame.south) {Some footer text};},
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{
  \lipsum[2]

  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-golden}

  \lipsum[3]
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{%
  Heading
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

How do I produce a PDF/ PNG file of a specific resolution/ aspect ratio?